# Full size window doesn't fit screen (Windows 7 Starter on Toshiba NB305 410)

Tags: windows-7, resolution

When I click the square at the upper right corner of a window to make it full size, it doesn't fit the screen properly.  The bottom of the window is always cut off, as if it thinks the screen is taller than it really is.  So status bars and essential buttons are often not visible, which is very annoying.  This started happening fairly recently.  How can I restore normal behavior?

Comment: It sounds like your need to reinstall your display adaptor to reset your screen area. Follow instructions from [here](http://superuser.com/q/455795/102661) (you may be able to complete this without booting into Safe Mode.